# Tkinter: is there a way to check checkboxes by default?

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

I have this piece of code that will create a simple checkbox :

```
from Tkinter import *

CheckVar = IntVar()
self.checkbutton = Checkbutton(self.root, text = "Test", variable = CheckVar)
```

However this checkbox in unchecked by default and I'm searching for a way to check it.

So far I have tried to insert

```
CheckVar.set(1)
```

right after CheckVar but it didn't work.

Thanks for your help

Edit : here is my full piece of code. When I run it, the box is still unchecked

```
from Tkinter import *

class App():
    def __init__(self, root):   
        self.root = root
        CheckVar = IntVar()
        CheckVar.set(1)
        self.checkbutton = Checkbutton(self.root, text = "Test", variable = CheckVar)
        self.checkbutton.grid(row=0, column=0,)


root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just tried it on my machine and it works perfectly. There must be a problem somewhere else in your code.

Comment: It should work. If not, then provide your full code related to this.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your `CheckVar` is a local variable. It's getting garbage collected. Save it as an object attribute. Also, you can create the variable and initialize it all in one step:

```
self.CheckVar = IntVar(value=1)
self.checkbutton = Checkbutton(..., variable = self.CheckVar)
```

You can also use the `select` function of the checkbutton:

```
self.checkbutton.select()
```

Comment: I am getting `'Checkbutton' has no attribute 'select'` with ttk 0.3.1

Comment: @xjcl: then you must be using the `Checkbutton` from ttk instead of tkinter.

Comment: Thank you @BryanOakley! What a frustration when looking at identical code occurring at different locations in the program and not getting the same result.

Answer (score 19):

I think the function you are looking for is `.select()`

This function selects the checkbutton (as can be assumed from the function name)

Try calling this function after your widget is defined:

```
from Tkinter import *

CheckVar = IntVar()
self.checkbutton = Checkbutton(self.root, text = "Test", variable = CheckVar)
self.checkbutton.select()
```

By calling the function right after the widget is created, it looks as though it's selected by default.

Answer (score 5):

Just adding onto GunnerStone's answer - Because I was looking for something where I can reset my values/checkboxes.

If you'd like to `de-select` the checkbox value for whatever reason, use `deselect()`:

```
from Tkinter import *

CheckVar = IntVar()
self.checkbutton = Checkbutton(self.root, text = "Test", variable = CheckVar)
self.checkbutton.deselect()
```

or use `toggle` to switch between the two:

`self.checkbutton.toggle()`

Answer (score 1):

I was using ttk and the only thing that worked was

```
self.checkbutton.state(["selected"])
```

Check the state via

```
"selected" in self.checkbutton.state()
```

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd just post the sample code that worked for me, this creates a checked checkbox.

```
window1 = tkinter.Tk()
check1 = tkinter.IntVar()

checkbox1 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window1, variable=check1, text="")
checkbox1.grid(row=0, column=0)
checkbox1.select()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var4 = IntVar(value=1)
Checkbutton(root, text="New", variable=var4, bg="light green").grid(row=12, column=0)
```

This will `check` all the check boxs.