# tkinter Checkbutton - how to create checked button at the start of app?

Tags: python, tkinter

Let's assume I have window with button as in code:

```
settings_window = tk.Toplevel()
settings_window.wm_title('Ustawienia')
grid = tk.BooleanVar()
c1 = tk.Checkbutton(settings_window, offvalue=False, onvalue=True, text="siatka", variable=grid, indicatoron=True).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='W')
```

And how I can achieve situation when after start button will be signed:
☑

Instead of being empty (not signed):
☐

I tried to use:
`state` option with `'active'`, `'normal'`, and `'disabled'`,
`indicatoron` option with `True`,

and:
`grid.set(True)`,
before `CheckButton`.
None of them helped.

Comment: It is not reproducible.

Comment: In this article? [Python, Tkinter : if there a way to check checkboxes by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37595078/9014308)

Answer (score 0):

`grid.set(True)` without any of those other extra options works fine for me:

```
import tkinter as tk

settings_window = tk.Toplevel()
settings_window.wm_title("Ustawienia")
grid = tk.BooleanVar()
grid.set(True)
c1 = tk.Checkbutton(
    settings_window,
    text="siatka",
    variable=grid,
).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="W")

tk.mainloop()
```