# unable to set default value for tkinter checkbox

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create checkbox with default value `True`,but it's not working, I tried plenty of the answers but didn't work

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Test v1")
        self.geometry("400x250")
        self.build_init()
    def build_init(self):
        #CheckVar = tk.BooleanVar(self,)
        CheckVar = tk.IntVar(value=1)
        checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(self, text = "Test", variable = CheckVar,onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        #checkbutton.select()
        checkbutton.place(x=20,y=80)
App().mainloop()
```

I coouln't find much on it in the documentaion other than `select` which didn't work, Also on this question [Tkinter: is there a way to check checkboxes by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595078/tkinter-is-there-a-way-to-check-checkboxes-by-default)

Comment: ```CheckVar.get()?```

Comment: @JoshuaNixon What do you mean ?

Comment: `CheckVar`, as a local variable, ceases to exist at the end of the function - leaving the Checkbutton with nowhere to store its state.

Comment: @jasonharper ok, but it should showw since I haven't yet left the function right?

Comment: Pretty much *nothing* in Tkinter happens immediately - updates to widget state get handled by the mainloop, so you've necessarily exited the function (and lost the Var) before the Checkbutton appears at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Test v1")
        self.geometry("400x250")
        self.build_init()
    def build_init(self):
        #CheckVar = tk.BooleanVar(self,)
        self.CheckVar = tk.IntVar(value=1)
        self.checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(self, text = "Test", variable = self.CheckVar,onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        #checkbutton.select()
        self.checkbutton.place(x=20,y=80)
App().mainloop()
```

Comment: It works for me though. try copy pasting the whole code. Your code already works, u just didn't add self in the checkvar and checkbutton

Comment: This does not work for me, I already have the variable assigned to self so it is not being garbage collected.  The button still renders initially unchecked even though the IntVar has a value of 1 and it will update to 0 and back to 1 as I interact with it.
Python 3.9