# Weird behavior of check-boxes in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I was learning about `checkbuttons` in `Tkinter` and I am stuck with this wierd issue. This is the code that I am using

```
root = Tk()
def showValue():
    print(val.get())
    Label(text=str(val.get())).pack()
val = StringVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Check me!", variable=val, onvalue="on", offvalue="off").pack()
Button(text="Click",command=showValue).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Firstly, the box is checked by default, which I think is because the `offvalue` is set to something i.e not False (*i.e not 0 or an empty string*), please correct me if I am wrong. But, the weird thing that I notice here is that when I hit the button, which should ideally show me a Label with `text="on"`, but actually it doesn't until I deselect the box manually, after which the button behaves normally. I know I couldn't explain whats happening here properly, but if you try it out yourself you would see it.
Here's an image of the GUI.
[image]

Now, the two blank lines that you see after the button is actually because I clicked the button twice before doing anything with the checkbox, and once I deselected the checkbox and then clicked the button, it displayed `off`. Can someone please what's actually happening here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set an initial value by `StringVar(value="off")` instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter: is there a way to check checkboxes by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595078/tkinter-is-there-a-way-to-check-checkboxes-by-default)

Comment: @stovfl Actually I know how to fix this, by deselecting the checkbox, but I wanted to know why is this happening?

Comment: ***wanted to know why is this happening?***: Your `var` is neither `onvalue="on"` nor `offvalue="off"` therefore the `Checkbox` is in **undefined** state. Read [The Tkinter Checkbutton Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use `StringVar(value="off")`. Also doing this `Label(text=str(val.get())).pack()` will cause memory leak but rather you have to use `config` to position your result at same position `Label.config(text=val.get())`. I have refactored the code to look more readable.

```
from tkinter import *


def showValue():
    Label.config(text=val.get())


root = Tk()


val = StringVar(value="off")
check = Checkbutton(root, text="Check me!", variable=val, onvalue="on", offvalue="off")
check.pack()

btn = Button(text="Click",command=showValue)
btn.pack()

lbl = Label(root)
lbl.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Once we are using StringVar(value="off"), we don't need if else in the function "showValue" because the "if" condition in this case never gets executed. Just "def showValue(): Label.config(text=val.get())" would be sufficient.